# Auto expand/contract formula array to correct size

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I have an array formula in a single cell.  The output wants to give an array but its size might be different each time and I don't immediately know the size.  Is there shortcut key I can press which will expand the formula to cover a correctly-sized array for the formula-array output?

Comment: You might want to consider showing the actual formula. Some might think that important.

Comment: Hi Jeeped, ..The formula might be as simple as a reference to a named array in a different workbook eg "=INDIRECT(Filepath & FileName & Field)" where the value in the cell called "Field" is set and changed by the user to denote a set of data which he wishes to access.  This might be a set of cashflows for deals with variable properties, so the length and with will vary considerably.  There are also a few other situations in which such a shortcut would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Excel, unlike google sheets, requires that a formula be put in each cell that an output is expected.  So in short no, there is not a native formula that will do this.  You can do this with IFERRORS,IF and other nested formulas, that would return a null text field after the data listed, but again would require a formula in each cell to the extent of the largest the list could be.  Or you can use vba and create a subroutine that will fill the area.

Comment: Thanks Scott.  The thing is I've seen & used such a thing many times at my previous work years ago.  Though perhaps it worked due to some in-house add-in library.  I just had to press Alt-Something(?) and a single cell would expand to occupy the appropriate number of neighbouring cells as a formula array.  If the necessary cells were occupied I would get an error message.

Comment: Then someone had written a subroutine that was triggered by the shortcut key that did what you are wanting.